# FactoryGirl not creating associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a rails app that I'm trying to test. In this app, I have a Question model which has many Answers.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:text].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
  ...
end
```

and

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  ...
end
```

Here is a look at my factories.rb file in which I am trying to produce a question with many answers. (NOTE: I followed the example listed here https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=factorygirl%20associations exactly, unless I overlooked something that I'm not seeing.)

```
factory :question do
    sequence(:text) { |n| "What is #{n} + #{n}?" }

    factory :question_with_answers do
        transient do
            answers_count 5
        end

        after(:create) do |question, evaluator|
            create_list(:answer, evaluator.answers_count, question: question)
        end
    end
end

factory :answer do
    sequence(:text) { |n| "Sample Answer #{n}" }

    question
end
```

And here is a look at the spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Question do
  let!(:question) { FactoryGirl.create :question_with_answers }

  it "should have 5 anwers" do
    expect(question.answers.length).to eq 5
  end
end
```

When I run this basic spec, I get the following failure/error:

```
1) Question should have 5 anwers
 Failure/Error: expect(question.answers.length).to eq 5

   expected: 5
        got: 0

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/models/question_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm not sure why it is not associating the answers to the question. Am I overlooking something right under my nose? Thanks in advance.

Other possibly helpful info - I am using:
factorygirl 4.5.0
rails 4.1.5
rspec 3.1.0

Comment: try use id `create_list(:answer, evaluator.answers_count, question_id: question.id)`, if no then try assigning the question directly to each of answers. like `answer.question = question; answer.save!`

Comment: Unfortunately, subbing in question_id does not work either. I have already modified the spec to manually assign answers to questions, so I have it working - it just seemed like there was a better way to do this. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it figured out! All I had to do was actually assign the nested attributes to the create_list method in the factory like so:

```
factory :question do
    sequence(:text) { |n| "What is #{n} + #{n}?" }

    after(:create) do |question|
        question.answers = create_list(:answer, 5, question: question)
    end

    assessment
end
```

I am also no longer creating a factory within the factory (as in I eliminated the :question_with_answers factory) and instead just called the after(:create) method after assigning the properties. Hopefully this can help someone else who is having some trouble with this.